# How to pass a parameter to the initCompontents method on NetBeans [Java]

Tags: java, netbeans

As already said, I want to pass a parameter (`DefaulStyledDocument doc`) to the `initComponents` method on NetBeans, but it is an only-read method.
That parameter should be used by a `JtextPane`, initialized inside of it. 
How can I pass that parameter without creating a new method `myIntiComponents(DefaultStyledDocument doc)`?
This is what I wrote so far:

```
    package AppPackage;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
    import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
    import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

    /**
     *
     * 
     */
    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /** Creates new form MainFrame */
        public MainFrame() {


            final StyleContext cont = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrGray = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.gray);
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrGreen = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.GREEN);
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrBlue = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrRed = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.RED);
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrPink = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.PINK);
            final javax.swing.text.AttributeSet attrBlack = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLACK);
            DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument() {

                @Override
                public void insertString (int offset, String str, javax.swing.text.AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
                    super.insertString(offset, str, a);

                    String text = getText(0, getLength());
                    int before = findLastNonWordChar(text, offset);
                    if (before < 0) before = 0;
                    int after = findFirstNonWordChar(text, offset + str.length());
                    int wordL = before;
                    int wordR = before;

                    while (wordR <= after) {
                        if (wordR == after || String.valueOf(text.charAt(wordR)).matches("\\W")) {                     

                            if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(System)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlue, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(cpu)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlue, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(motherboard)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlue, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(gpu)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlue, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(screen)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlue, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(ram)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrGray, false);
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(psu)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrRed, false); 
                            else if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(time)"))
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrPink, false);

                            else
                                setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlack, false);
                            wordL = wordR;
                        }
                        wordR++;
                    }
                }


            myInitComponents(doc);         
        }

        private void myInitComponents(DefaultStyledDocument doc) {

         //all initilizations made by netbeans for my GUI..
         textField = new javax.swing.JTextPane(doc);
         //other initializations..
         }
}
```

so, what I did so far is to copy the method `initComponets` to another method named `myInitComponents(DefaultStyledDocument doc)`, deleting in the constructor the call for the `initComponents` method.

Comment: Mind providing the code developed so far?

Comment: @pino since you cant modify `initComponents()` method you can't pass parameters to it

Comment: @pino you can pass parameters to `MainFrame()` constructor  and use it .or you can use variable without parameters .